# Webcontrol with text property that can hold server controls

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am designing a control and i need it to inherit from a class that has a text property that can contain server controls.

Here's an example to illustrate what i'm trying to explain

```
<asp:myCustomControl id="myCustomControl1" runat="server" someProperty="something">
    <asp:hyperlink id="myCustomControl1Hyperlink" runat="server" navigateUrl="someUrl">
        Click here
    </asp:hyperlink>
</asp:myCustomControl>


Protected Overrides Sub Render( _
    ByVal writer As HtmlTextWriter)

    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Text) Then
        writer.Write( _
            "some html" + _
            Text + _
            "some other html"
        )
    End If

End Sub
```

The goal of this is that i can decide how to render the control in the `render` function of my control, while showing the what would be `Text` property in my control.

My first try was to inherit from `literal` as this would let me write `<a>` tags inside without any problems. But, recently I had to change the `<a>` tags by `<asp:hyperlink>` tags and it will raise a `'{0}' does not allow child controls.` exception.

So I tried changing it so it inherits from `panel`, but this time, in my render function, I can't use the `Text` property, neither the Me.Text, as they both doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You inherits from `Control` Class, and you solve all problems

Comment: `Control` doesn't have a `Text` property either.

Comment: you add this property in child control, and build